# Why its not recommended to use pointer for array access in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I'm learning C programming and I cam across this tutorial online, which state that you should always prefer using [] operator over pointer arithmetic as much as possible.

https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/C_arrays.html#dynamic

> you can use pointer arithmetic (but in general don't)

consider the following code in C

```
int    *p_array;
p_array = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*50);

for(i=0; i < 50; i++) {
  p_array[i] = 0;
}
```

What is the difference in doing it using pointer arithmetic like the following code **(and why its not recommended)**?

```
int    *p_array;
p_array = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*50);      // allocate 50 ints

int *dptr = p_array;

for(i=0; i < 50; i++) {
  *dptr = 0;
  dptr++;
}
```

**What are the cases where using pointer arithmetic can cause issues in the software? is it bad practice or is it inexperienced engineer can be not paying attention?**

Comment: That's a silly rule. Use whatever is most fitting or natural for the task at hand.

Comment: The pointer-based code is bad, not least because it's longer. `for (int *dptr = ptr; dptr < ptr + 50; ++dptr) *dptr = 0;` would be fine.

Comment: Sometimes the bracket form is easier to read... but in the example given here,  I'd consider either one to be just fine (just a matter of preference).  I'd usually prefer `ptr[i]` over `*(ptr + i)`, though.  As long as it's easy to follow and you still have a reference to the start of the array, it's not that important.

Comment: The real rule is code things in the way that's easiest to read and understand. It's probably true that indexing is better than pointer arithmetic in this sense in a majority of cases, but there are certainly cases where pointers are the natural choice.  A completely different topic: in C, _don't_ cast the result of `malloc`. It's unnecessary clutter.

Comment: Another nit about your tutorial... There is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: We have to be careful that answers don’t end up as opinion based to this question.

Comment: Re: casting result from malloc(): I do it for two reasons: for code-based documentation of the intended use of the buffer, and to give the compiler a chance to check that intended type against the assigned variable in the assignment (compile-time checks are your friend).  If you and your future coders are perfect, you could save the 10 to 20 characters.

Comment: Re; the pointer-based example above:  As written, it leaves dptr pointing beyond the allocated buffer, which could lead to misuse of the pointer.  But of course the array form can always be misused in the same way: `p_array[50]`  In either case, I would avoid the magic number 50 and of course check for NULL returned by malloc().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is not recommended:

```
int    *p_array;
p_array = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*50);      // allocate 50 ints

int *dptr = p_array;

for(i=0; i < 50; i++) {
  *dptr = 0;
  dptr++;
}
```

because 1) for no reason you have two different pointers that point to the same place, 2) you don't check the result of `malloc()` -- it's known to return NULL occasionally, 3) the code is not easy to read and 4) it's easy to make a silly mistake very hard to spot later on.

All in all, I'd recommend to use this instead:

```
int array[50] = { 0 };  // make sure it's zero-initialized
int* p_array = array;   // if you must =)
```

Comment: its point 2 and 4 I'm looking for, can you add an example of 4, thank you!

Comment: @mamounothman I can give you **20** pointer mistakes, take a look at this page: https://www.acodersjourney.com/top-20-c-pointer-mistakes/

Comment: your example is not dynamic memory allocation, which is supposed to be the point of the tutorial he's following. you're allocating on the stack

Answer (score 2):

Since there seems to be all out confusion on this:

In the old days, we had 16bit CPU's think 8088, 268 etc.
To formulate an address you had to load your segment register (16 bit register) and your address register. if accessing an array, you could load your array base into the segment register and the address register would be the index.
C compilers for these platforms did exist but pointer arithmetic involved checking the address for overruns and bumping the segment register if necessary (inefficient) Flat addressed pointers simply weren't possible in hardware.

Fast forward to the 80386  Now we have a full 32 bit space. Hardware pointers are possible Index + base addressing incurs a 1 clock cycle penalty. The segments are also 32 bit though, so arrays can be loaded using segments avoiding this penalty even if you are running 32 bit mode. The 368 also increases the number of segment registers by 2. (No idea why Intel thought that was a good idea) There was still a lot of 16bit code around though

These days, segment registers are disabled in 64 bit mode, Base+Index addressing is free.

Is there any platform where a flat pointer can outperform array addressing in hardware ?  Well yes. the Motorola 68000 released in 1979 has a flat 32 bit address space, no segments and the Base + Index addressing mode incurs an 8 clock cycle penalty over immediate addressing. So if you're programming a early 80's era Sun station, Apple Lisa etc. this might be relevant.

In short. If you want an array, use an array. If you want a pointer use a pointer. Don't try and out smart your compiler. Convoluted code to turn arrays into pointers is exceedingly unlikely to provide any benefit, and may be slower.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, without compiler optimizations, pointer arithmetic may be more efficient, because it is easier to just increment a pointer than to calculate a new offset in every single loop iteration. However, most modern CPUs are optimized in such a way that accessing memory with an offset does not incur a (significant) performance penalty.

Even if you happen to be programming on a platform in which pointer arithmetic is faster, then it is likely that, if you activate compiler optimizations ("-O3" on most compilers), the compiler will use whatever method is fastest.

Therefore, it is mostly a matter of personal preference whether you use pointer arithmetic or not.

Code using array indexing instead of pointer arithmetic is generally easier to understand and less prone to errors.

Another advantage of not using pointer arithmetic is that [pointer aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing) may be less of an issue (because you are using less pointers). That way, the compiler may have more freedom in optimizing your code (making your code faster).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Thanks for your explanation on the downvote. I have now inserted the word "generally" into my answer to make clear that it this may not apply to all platforms. I have no idea why someone might object to the last paragraph, though.

Comment: Well, what prompted the comment was there isn't a direct correlation between not using pointer arithmetic and the strict aliasing rule. (you could have an array of pointers, etc...) You are correct in the sense that if you are not casting/dereferencing then there is no possibility to *type-pun* a pointer, but the `[..]` does act as a dereference on its own. (But regardless, it was pretty apparent what you were saying...)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: My main point is that using pointer arithmetic instead of indexing generally requires less use of pointers. For example, the pointer arithmetic code posted by the OP uses two pointers, whereas the indexing code uses only one pointer (because only the base pointer is required). The more pointer variables you are using in your code, the higher the chance that the compiler might have issues in ruling out pointer aliasing (which prevents optimizations).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: I just noticed that the Clang, gcc and Microsoft C++ compilers all don't seem to use incremented pointers on x64, but indexing, even with full optimizations. It appears that the CPUs are optimized for this in such a way that there is no additional cost to calculating a new offset in every single loop iteration. This is surprising for me, as I would have expected at least some (at least minor) performance penalty. Therefore, it seems that my answer was indeed wrong for x64 CPUs. I'm not sure about other platforms, though. I have therefore edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes, most compilers will optimize iteration with pointers to an indexed expression. It's more semantics of how easy it is to implement one or the other in the underlying assembly. There have been a couple of posts about that issue alone and the takeaway is with optimization -- it's up to the compiler on how it wants to do it. Both are fine from a written C standpoint.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel read the Intel developers manual. Most instructions come with an offset address mode available so the index addressing generates no extra machine instructions, and no extra cycles either

Comment: down voting as this answer is plain wrong. There is no efficiency advantage.

Comment: @camelccc: Thanks for pointing out the reason for your downvote and also for pointing out that modern Intel processors have no performance penalty for indexing. However, at the time of your downvote, I had already removed all claims of indexing generally being slower than incrementing a poiner. Instead, I now use the word "may" to indicate that there is the possibility of it being slower, depending on the platform. But the conclusion of my answer is that indexing is still generally better, because the optimizer can be trusted to do the right thing and because pointers have other disadvantages.